# I want to read from and write to a file in C#

Tags: c#, file

here is my code without files

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
    BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();
    BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devs = bc.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
    foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devs)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(d.DeviceName);
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("finish");
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Instead of the line `System.Console.WriteLine(d.DeviceName);`
I want that part to be written into a file.

After that I need to loop on that file, and for each device name in that file, I will search in another file for it's corresponding output. A hint on how to  loop on and search in files will be sufficient for that part.

Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: whao - google must be broken again :)

Comment: Rene - your comment in the deleted answer said it all -wish I could upvote you for that simple act of humilty in deleting your answer due to the OP not bothering to track your suggested links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [File.AppendAllText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) as an exact drop-in (but you'll need to append Environment.NewLine to your text).

Make sure that you delete the file if it exists before your foreach loop, possibly prompting the user for confirmation depending on your requirements.